# homeomorphism represented by function

Tags: ergodic-theory

I know that if $f$ is representing homeomorphism $T$ and $f^0(x)=x,f^1(x)=f(x),...,f^n(x)=f(f^{n-1}(x))$ for $n\geq1$, then $f^n$ is monotone and $f^n(x+k)=f^n(x)+k$ for every integer $k$, but why among all functions representing homeomorphism $T$ there is unique function $f$ such that $0\leq f(0)<1$?

Comment: This could use some context IMO. What are the domains and codomains of $f$ and $T$? What does it mean to represent a homeomorphism by a function?

Comment: So let's consider a homeomorphism T of the unit circle $S^1$ ($S^1$ is identified with interval $[0,1)$)and T is preserving orientation, then there exists a continuous strictly increasing function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $T(x)=\{f(x)\}$ for $ x\in [0,1)$. Then we say that f represents T.